# How to programatically get a TabControl's Children

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code that used to work for me. I'm using this as a placeholder as I always end up nesting a TabControls within another one.

```
public partial class MyTabControl : TabControl {

    public TabControl _tc { get { return ((Grid)Content).Children[0] as TabControl; } }
}
```

I recently updated a few nuget packages however (`MahApps.Metro` and its dependencies) and now I'm getting the error `The name 'Content' does not exist in the current context`.

I'm not sure if the nuget package should have affected this though as I'm subclassing WPF's `TabControl`. Does anyone know of a workaround to get the same result? I basically just want to be able to programatically call on the TabControl's children.

Comment: 1) Don't subclass controls in WPF 2) Don't construct the UI in code in WPF

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not using this code to construct UI. I know it's kind of hacky but it's simply for convenience as I'm writing loads of TabControls with nested TabControls

Comment: A TabControl does not have TabControl children. You probably wanted to get a TabItem. Besides that, you may use the TabControl's `ItemContainerGenerator` to get access to a TabItem for a specific item or index.

Comment: Thanks Clemens! I think you're right. I'll try googling `ItemContainerGenerator`

Answer (score 0):

A `TabControl` has a `SelectedContent` property that returns the content of the currently selected tab:

```
public partial class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    public TabControl _tc { get { return ((Grid)SelectedContent).Children[0] as TabControl; } }
}
```

For this to work, it assumes that the selected tab actually contains a `Grid` with a nested `TabControl`:

```
<local:MyTabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <Grid>
            <TabControl />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</local:MyTabControl>
```